# Airflow keeps running my DAG, despite catchup=False, schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

Tags: airflow-scheduler

Similar to previous questions, but none of the answers given worked. I have a DAG:

```
import datetime
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator
from airflow.operators import BashOperator

PROJECT = os.environ['PROJECT']
GCS_BUCKET = os.environ['BUCKET']
API_KEY = os.environ['API_KEY']

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'catchup': False
}

dag = DAG('dag-name',
          schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(hours=2),
          default_args=default_args,
          max_active_runs=1,
          concurrency=1,
          catchup=False)

DEFAULT_OPTIONS_TEMPLATE = {
    'project': PROJECT,
    'stagingLocation': 'gs://{}/staging'.format(GCS_BUCKET),
    'tempLocation': 'gs://{}/temp'.format(GCS_BUCKET)
}

def my-dataflow-job(template_location, name):
    run_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    a_value = run_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')

    t1 = DataflowTemplateOperator(
        task_id='{}-task'.format(name),
        template=template_location,
        parameters={'an_argument': a_value},
        dataflow_default_options=DEFAULT_OPTIONS_TEMPLATE,
        poll_sleep=30
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='{}-loader-heartbeat'.format(name),
        bash_command='curl --fail -XGET "[a heartbeat URL]" --header "Authorization: heartbeat_service {1}"'.format(name, API_KEY)
    )

    t1 >> t2

with dag:
    backup_bt_to_bq('gs://[path to gcs]'.format(GCS_BUCKET), 'name')
```

As you can see, I'm trying very hard to prevent Airflow from trying to backfill. Yet, when I deploy the DAG (late in the day, on 7/30/2019), it just keeps running the DAG one after the other, after the other, after the other.

Since this task is moving a bit of data around, this is not desirable. How do I get airflow to respect the "run this every other hour" schedule_interval??

As you can see, I've set `catchup: False` in both the DAG args AND the default args (just in case, started with them in the DAG args). The retry delay is also a long period.

Each DAG run is reported as a success.
I'm running with the following version:

composer-1.5.0-airflow-1.10.1

My next step is kubernetes cron...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did not have `catchup=False` when you first created the dag.  I think airflow may not recognize changes to the catchup parameter after inital dag creation.

Try renaming it and see what happens.  E.g. add a v2 and enable it.  After enabling it, it will run once even though catchup is false, because there is a valid completed interval (i.e. current time is >= start_time + schedule_interval), but that is all.

Of course, test with a fake operator that doesn't do anything expensive.

Comment: I did have it enabled. And have tried a few names. Probably just going to dump in k8s cron.

Comment: Maybe if you update the code in your question I might be able to find an issue.  It is clear that the code you have posted is not up to date: `my-dataflow-job` is not a valid function name, and `backup_bt_to_bq` is not defined anywhere.